# Multi project gradle build deployed as 2 separate applications (one is a play app)

Tags: java, gradle, playframework

I am working on migrating a java multi project build based on net beans into a gradle build.
The motivation is not to be dependant on the IDE and having gradle manage all the dependencies.

we currently have one folder that contains all the projects and they have their inter dependencies.
These projects are deployed in two separate applications. One (lets call it App1) in a play framework application (v1.4) that depends on some other projects, and the other (App2) is a regular java application deployed on a separate machine.
Some projects are common to both applications.

I currently managed to build App2 using gradle, so I have a build.gradle & settings.gradle files in the top folder
now I want to add the build files for App1 (the play application).

Questions:
1. I couldn't find any explanations on combining play 1.x with gradle. Does anyone know how to do it?
2. How should I arrange my top level gradle files for building 2 separate applications
3. I want to be able to use the IDE for refactoring code that is common to both apps. how do I do that

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your questions

Suppose your projects structure looks like in below image

[image: project struture]

Please include all sub projects in top level project's settings.gradle like below image

[image: top level project settings.xml]

Use the dependencies in sub projects like below image

[image: sub project build.gradle that is used other sub project as dependency]